# newline sequence counts as one character?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, newline, wc

Does the newline sequence or even all escape sequences in a file count as only one character, even though it's written `\n`?

After I separated a one-line-file into multiple lines, only one character per line was added according to the `wc -m` output of the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` is a way of representing a newline character in various languages and programs but as the name suggests, a newline is only stored in a file as a single character.

The backslash helps both computers and humans to realise you are referring to a newline character without you having to actually type one, which would be confusing in a lot of instances.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` notation is usually used for a single character. Use a hexdump to see the actual bytes, for example `xxd`.